# Magento: updated product's image doesn't appear in frontend

Tags: image, magento, product, appearance

I opened a product, deleted it's images and uploaded other 2 instead. They appeared in backend.
I refreshed the cache, deleted the cache of images in `System=>Cache Management`. I deleted cache of images in `media/catalog/product/cache` manually. I deleted the cache in `var/cache`, deleted the cache in `var/minifycache` (I have Fooman Speedster), updated indexes in index management. I deleted the cache in my browser.

Finally, the previous images still were present. WTF? I hit all the delete/refresh-buttons again and again, 10 times, I deleted all the possible and impossible caches manually from a file system. Result: the new images didn't appear.

I got very angry after 2 hours of trying.

I deleted those old images from the file system.

The new images did't appear, now I have a default image of Magento for a product.

I tried to access the new images directly (e.g. http://mysite.com/media/catalog/products/o/1.jpg), and the images are loaded and found without problems.

The new images are showed in backend fine.

What the hell is happening? How to get rid of it and, finally, to go bad at 5 a.m.??? Thank everybody for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only advice is to double and triple check that you've flush all caches possible (Magento Cache, System Cache, and all 8 caches along with media cache). If you're using Zend Full Page cache, empty that too. Go to /var/cache and delete everything in here and do the same in var/sessions (if you're storing sessions in the file system and not the database).

If all of that fails try using a different browser that you have yet to view the site on. If that fails try uploading a fresh copy of *your version* of magento, replacing all the core files. I've seen crazy things happen with Magento and a upload of a clean copy fixes problems for whatever reason. Hope this helps!

Comment: Not a whole lot of people bahaha, magento is tricky, be sure to always check a product's status!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem myself. Don't forget to look externally as well, such as in the case of varnish/pagespeed/some CDN, and pay close attention to the URLs. I spent about an hour scratching my head wondering why it wasn't working when I was purging the wrong thing (www.example.com instead of media.example.com).

Answer (score 0):

just try on command

php bin/magento catalog:image:resize

then

reindex command

your system will work perfectly.